# Show tests results from custom plugin (utplsql)

Tags: junit, plsql, sonarqube

I'm using sonar for quite a long time and for me it is really great tool. Nowadays with plsql based project I have decided to use utplsql maven plugin to watch plsql tests results. Utplsql plugin outputs reports in junit like xml format. Unfortunately sonar is not presenting data from utplsql reports. This is plsql so there is no coverage or real java test classes - just an xml report. How to feed sonar just to view tests results,  only main statistics like failed, success, all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [Generic Test Coverage](http://docs.codehaus.org/x/zIFMDg) plugin. It will not be able to import directly xUnit type reports, but a bit of XSLT should allow you to convert to the correct format.

Comment: Great, I tried,  but have a problem with tested java file set in generic test xml.
File exists, same error with relativ and absolute path.

20:31:14.981 INFO  - Sensor GenericCoverageSensor...
20:31:14.987 INFO  - Imported coverage data for 0 files
20:31:14.987 INFO  - Imported IT coverage data for 0 files
20:31:15.006 INFO  - Parsing gen.xml
20:31:15.121 INFO  - Imported unit test data for 0 files
20:31:15.121 INFO  - unit test data ignored for 1 unknown files, including:
src/main/java/aaa/App.java
20:31:15.121 INFO  - Sensor GenericCoverageSensor done: 140 ms